# Testing NIFI: best practices

Tags: api-testing, rest-api, data-driven, api, back-end

I do have new task related to test NIFI Apache.
not sure where to start or how to.

- I have one thing in mind to test it as an API but the only response it sends is status code.
- I know also it has be Data driven, based on the data NIFI's listeners will route the data to the appropriate DB

I appreciate your thoughts and suggestions

Comment: Here is a good start, https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDF1/HDF-1.2.0.1/bk_DeveloperGuide/content/testing.html

Answer (score 1):

I think someone might need some answer in the futuer in they were working on something slimier:

I have divided the testing on two phases

- functional test, it handeled each processor/processors group(nifi entities)
  the Test Cases where built to test what each processor's doing on Json file (modify extract and/or conversion)
- integration test, all the test cases were designed  to test how is nifi is integrating with logging reception using TCP/HTTP listener and DB insertion into DB (after converting the json into sql query ) /KAfka